# SPO list migration from one tenant to another with Graph API and Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, microsoft-graph, content-migration

I am currently working on a project that has me doing migrations from one SPO tenant to another. I do not currently have access to most popular tools like ShareGate, Metalogicx etc. I mainly have to use free services like Mover.io, SharePoint Migration tool, powershell and Graph API.

I was able to successfully move document libraries over to the new tenant using a combination of powershell and Mover.io. But now I am attempting to get lists moved over but I am not sure how to migrate sharepoint lists on mass.

The only idea I had was to save the lists as templates and then export the XMLs and import into the new environment. I only know of a way to do this manual. I need to gather all the list types within the site collection (excluding document libraries) and items. Then recreate them in the new tenant.
Is there another free tool I can utilize to migrate lists on mass and recreate them in t the destination?
If not is there a Powershell script I can use along with the GraphAPI?

Any direction or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you